# Find and remove defined elements in text

Tags: php, regex

I have lines of text like so:

```
CPU: Intel Core i7 970 $580
Mobo: Gigabyte X58A-UD5 $300
RAM: Kingston 6x 4GB DDR3 $230
HDD: Samsung Spinpoint F3 1TB $70
GPU: 1GB Nvidia GeForce GTS450 $113
Case: Antec P183 $135
PSU: Seasonic M12II 520W $113
ODD: Samsung SG-B083A $29
CPU HSF: Coolermaster Hyper 212 $30
```

I wish to remove the `CPU:`, `Mobo:` etc bits (so basically anything behind `:` [notice the space]) .

Further to this, I wish to remove the price bit on the end - `$580` etc.

Something like this should work right?

```
preg_replace('/\$([0-9\.]+)/', $PC_Specs);
```

It's so I can store the product name in a variable.

Thanks greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something more like:

```
preg_replace('/(^\w+:\s*|\$\d*\.?\d+\s*$)/m', '', $PC_Specs);
```

For one thing I added the empty string as a second parameter, which is needed to tell preg_replace what to replace the matches with. I also modified the regex to match two distinct sub expressions:

`^\w+:\s*` Matches start of line with at least one word character followed by a colon and 0 or more spaces.

`\$(\d*\.?\d+\s*$` Matches a dollar sign followed by a number with a possible decimal point and zero or more spaces before the end of the line.

I added the `/m` modifier to make it multiline regex too, which you need if you are passing the whole thing in as one. If you are passing in an array of lines then you can remove that.

**EDIT** In response to comment:

```
$PC_Specs = 
'CPU: Intel Core i7 970 $580
Mobo: Gigabyte X58A-UD5 $300
RAM: Kingston 6x 4GB DDR3 $230
HDD: Samsung Spinpoint F3 1TB $70
GPU: 1GB Nvidia GeForce GTS450 $113
Case: Antec P183 $135
PSU: Seasonic M12II 520W $113
ODD: Samsung SG-B083A $29
CPU HSF: Coolermaster Hyper 212 $30';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^(\w+):\s*(.*?)\s*\$\d*\.?\d+\s*$/m', $PC_Specs, $matches);
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++)
    ${strtolower($matches[1][$i])} = $matches[2][$i];
```

After the above code runs,

`$cpu` will be `"Intel Core i7 970"`

`$mobo` will be `"Gigabyte X58A-UD5"`

`$ram` will be `"Kingston 6x 4GB DDR3"`

etc... :)

Comment: Thanks, but each line has to have a variable... so this wont work. Like: $cpu = "Intel Core i7 970" etc (obviously dynamic)

Comment: @Dean, oh haha, I missed that bit in your original question. I will update my post. Is this an array of lines, or a single string containing all the lines?

Comment: Single string containing all the lines. A user enters in the details via a TEXTFIELD or similar (on a form, bit like a pastebin).

Comment: this is very user reliant though right? ie. if a user has this: `InappropriateWord: test $20` it will have $InappropriateWord for the variable right? I guess I can just check if they entered it in correctly, but I'd like to have set variables, if you get what I mean. Eg. $CPU, $RAM, $MB, $GPU which arent set on the text entered by a user.

Comment: @Dean You could use an associative array instead, you are right that if this is coming from the user you do not want to let them set variables like this. I'm not sure what would happen if the entered `Matches: ` haha but it wouldn't be good.

Comment: Use `strtolower($matches[1][$i])` as the key in a an associative array and then you can look for specific values in that array and ignore anything extra. You just need to change the line `${strtolower($matches[1][$i])} = $matches[2][$i];` to something like `$arr[strtolower($matches[1][$i])] = $matches[2][$i];` and declare $arr as an array before the loop

Comment: I tried this, I don't think its right though... because its just returning "Array". http://pastebin.com/zADMJuPN I should probably stop bothering you and figure it out myself... thanks again.

Comment: cheers - understand it alot better now. Will have a play around.